# Make target in subdirectory Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project with the following structure:

```
/project
 |
 |-/pythonsrc
 |  |- Makefile
 |  |- ...
 |
 |-/javasrc
 |  |- Makefile
 |  |- ...
 |
 |- Makefile
```

In `/project/pythonsrc/Makefile` I have a rule:

```
.Phony: format-python-code
format-python-code:
    black .
```

I'd like to be able to run `make format_python_code` from /project (without duplicating the rule or writing a rule that calls the subrule)  and from /project/pythonsrc. Can I expose rules in subdirectory Makefiles at the top level? Is this possible?

Comment: Try `make -C pythonsrc format_python_code`. Note: `.Phony:` should be `.PHONY:`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to be able to run `make format_python_code` from /project (without duplicating the rule or writing a rule that calls the subrule) and from /project/pythonsrc. Can I expose rules in subdirectory Makefiles at the top level? Is this possible?

**TL;DR**: maybe.

Generally speaking, execution of rules' recipes is sensitive to context, especially working directory.  That leads to two main approaches to splitting `make` rules among multiple files:

- **structure your build system for recursive `make`.**  The expectation here is that each makefile will be the controlling file for its own `make` execution, running with the directory of the makefile as working directory.  These will be used by makefiles farther up the chain via a recursive `make` invocation of this form (or an equivalent):

  ```
  make -C subdir some_target
  ```

**OR**

- **use `include` to form a single set of `make` instructions from multiple inputs.**  The expectation here is that all `make` inputs, taken together in the order `include`d will form a single cohesive makefile for a non-recursive `make`.  All rules, in whatever file they are located, must therefore anticipate being run with the top-level directory as working directory.

**For the most part, these are incompatible.**  Thus, it is usual in the latter case to name the included files something different from `makefile` or `Makefile` to avoid giving the impression that these can be used standalone.

In your particular case, if your top-level makefile performed an `include pythonsrc/Makefile`, then that would provide a `format_python_code` target in the top-level makefile.  The recipe of that rule would not mean the same thing when run from the top-level directory as when run from the `pythonsrc` directory via recursive `make`, but it is conceivable that it would nevertheless produce the desired effect.

But **you should not do that**.  It is a recipe for disaster because you get everything else from the subdirectory makefile too, and because if you do happen to get the desired effect by running the rule from a top-level `make`, then that's mostly a matter of happenstance, not design.